# Need a bit of help on XSS

Tags: xss

I am trying to execute an XSS on a website, but when I insert the following

```
< and > (less than and greater than signs)
```

It changes to:

```
❮ and ❯
```

I have tried the following attributes from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

When I insert the attributes from OWASP, I would still get `❮ and ❯`, so that wasn't helpful.

Would anyone be able to give me more insight on this? Please and thanks.

I am just looking to bypass `< and >` - that's all.

Some information on the website: It's HTML5. (If that helps)

Comment: Anyone to help me? It's kind of hard.

Comment: So, you try to insert `<` and `>` into an input box and those 2 characters are automatically converted to `❮` and `❯`?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I've tried multiple methods, but maybe you can help me @ROMANIA_engineer

Comment: Anyone think they can help me here....?